# Book called “The Purple Planet”

Tags: story-identification, books

My first sci-fi book was in the 60s. It was called to my best recollection *The Purple Planet*. Any ideas what it was?

Comment: Is there anything else to go on?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP simply provided the name of what he was looking for

Comment: @Shevliaskovic - It's a relatively obscure book. I'm not surprised he couldn't find it.

Answer (score 9):

You're possibly referring to the novella "[The Purple Planet](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/beresford_leslie)" by Leslie Beresford.

It was written in the 1920s and republished as a serial called "[Gods of the Purple Planet](http://efanzines.com/FWD/FWD27.htm)" at some point in the early 1960s.